# PHP: MYSQL Query returns wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote a function in php which updates a mysql-table according to a given array.
Before updating, I check whether there already exists an entry with the same ‚description‘-value.

```
// $fachtyp is given by foreach
$query = "SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM fachtyp WHERE `Description`='$fachtyp'),'true','false')"
    . " AS existance";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$exists = ($row['existance'] === 'true');
if (!$exists) { /* update */ }
```

The problemis as follows: When I debugged this, i recognised $row['exists'] to be twhile debugging) to return 'false' in netbeans. How can this happen??

Thx fer reply, Lukas

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: You're comparing it to `'true'` as a string. Try replacing it with == true (with out quotes)?

Comment: @OfirBaruch That seems like the answer, so you should post it as such.

Comment: just wondering why you choose to use such SQL query when PHP can perfectly fine use inner `SELECT 1 ...` and act accordingly?

Comment: did you tried to use `var_dump($row);` to see what actually is returned as result?

Comment: I don't think you're selecting what you think you're selecting...

Comment: The comparison cannot be the problem, because $row['existance'] is "true" before this line. Also, the sql result is not referred as boolean, bacause I used IF(…,'true','false') instead of IF(…,1,0).
@ivan-husnjak what do you mean by that?
The thought about SQL-Injection are noticed, I'll check that out.

Comment: @ofir: OP is selecting out true/false STRINGS `IF(condition, 'true', 'false')`. comparing against php true/false values would kind of work, but would also be the incorrect test.

Comment: @MarcB , After re-thinking it - I got that point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check what is actually the query and returned result:

```
echo $query; // debug query
var_dump($row); // see what is returned
```

I would suggest you replace the sql query (unless you really have to have it executed like that) with simpler query, and work out the logic (true, false) with php:

```
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM fachtyp WHERE `Description`='$fachtyp'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$exists = (bool) mysqli_num_rows($result); // just count returned rows is enough to determine if value exists in database
if (!$exists) { /* update */ }
```

Also if `$fachtyp` value is coming from request (GET or POST value, actually even if it does not come from request), you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize value before putting it into query.

Comment: Yep, dats workin. But anyway I wonder why the values wer that different… I tracked everything with xdebug on netbeans…